# How can I rearrange the order of Bootstrap columns based on screen size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to configure 3 cells using Bootstrap 5 that will be rendered slightly different on Desktop and Mobile display. Can we do this with Bootstrap 5?

[image: Here is what I want to achieve]

Do I have to use CSS Grid instead of Bootstrap 5 classes?

```css
div.purple100 {
  background: purple;
  height: 100px;
}

div.orange100 {
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
}

div.orange200 {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
}

div.green100 {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 green100"></div>
      <div class="col-12 purple100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 orange200"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7 green100"></div>
  <div class="col-5 orange100"></div>
  <div class="col-12 purple100"></div>
</div>
```